# eclipse pydev: unable to create pydev project

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've successfully installed pydev into eclipse:

[image]

Anyway, I'm unable to use my existing python sources to create a pydev project. When I click File > New > Project, there's no pydev

[image]

What can I do to create new pydev project?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Did you restart Eclipse?

Comment: You should use a standalone version. Less bloated. But since Eclipse is built like a russian tank ...

Comment: what do you mean a standalone version? I've just downloaded the most standard eclipse installation and installed pydev the way that everybody recommends...

Comment: @w.m yes, I did, twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I've found that version of JDK was wrong. I must have installed jdk6 first, then eclipse, then install jdk7 and then installed pydev. My default jdk was 6 (this can be changed, as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default)). When eclipse is fired from jdk6, it will never see pydev. When I run eclipse manually under jdk7, pydev appeared :)

```
./eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/bin/java
```

so make sure you use jdk7 to run eclipse and it should be fine.

Comment: From http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html:  Since version 3.0, PyDev requires Eclipse 3.8 or 4.3 onwards and Java 7! For older versions, keep using PyDev 2.x.